# upload fails with image greater than 800kb

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, upload

I have a form where i can drag and drop an image into a canvas and then click an upload button to upload the file to the server.  Below is my javascript file and php file.  I cannot find where or why this will not allow me to upload something greater than 800kb? I believe its all failing in the php at if(file_put_contents($uploaddir.$randomName, $decodedData)) { but again i dont know why?  The sql statment fails to by the way thats why i think its failing at that point in the php file. 32M is php max file size upload.

**UPDATE...** i removed anything to do with uploading with php in the php and only left `echo $randomName.":uploaded successfully";`    which now leads me to believe there is something wrong in the JS file at `$.post('/mods/photogallery/manager/upload.php?gpID=' + bla, dataArray[index], function(data) {` for anything greater than 800kb (ish)

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Makes sure the dataTransfer information is sent when we
    // Drop the item in the drop box.
    jQuery.event.props.push('dataTransfer');

    var z = -40;
    // The number of images to display
    var maxFiles = 1;
    var errMessage = 0;

    // Get all of the data URIs and put them in an array
    var dataArray = [];

    // Bind the drop event to the dropzone.
    $('#drop-files').bind('drop', function(e) {

        // Stop the default action, which is to redirect the page
        // To the dropped file

        var files = e.dataTransfer.files;

        // Show the upload holder
        $('#uploaded-holder').show();
        $('#drop-files').hide();

        // For each file
        $.each(files, function(index, file) {

            // Some error messaging
            if (!files[index].type.match('image.*')) {

                if(errMessage == 0) {
                    $('#drop-files').html('Hey! Images only');
                    ++errMessage
                }
                else if(errMessage == 1) {
                    $('#drop-files').html('Stop it! Images only!');
                    ++errMessage
                }
                else if(errMessage == 2) {
                    $('#drop-files').html("Can't you read?! Images only!");
                    ++errMessage
                }
                else if(errMessage == 3) {
                    $('#drop-files').html("Fine! Keep dropping non-images.");
                    errMessage = 0;
                }
                return false;
            }

            // Check length of the total image elements

            if($('#dropped-files > .image').length < maxFiles) {
                // Change position of the upload button so it is centered
                var imageWidths = ((220 + (40 * $('#dropped-files > .image').length)) / 2) - 20;
                $('#upload-button').css({'left' : imageWidths+'px', 'display' : 'block'});
            }

            // Start a new instance of FileReader
            var fileReader = new FileReader();

                // When the filereader loads initiate a function
                fileReader.onload = (function(file) {

                    return function(e) { 

                        // Push the data URI into an array
                        dataArray.push({name : file.name, value : this.result});

                        // Move each image 40 more pixels across
                        z = z+40;
                        var image = this.result;


                        // Just some grammatical adjustments
                        if(dataArray.length == 1) {
                            $('#upload-button span').html("1 file to be uploaded");
                        } else {
                            $('#upload-button span').html(dataArray.length+" files to be uploaded");
                        }
                        // Place extra files in a list
                        if($('#dropped-files > .image').length < maxFiles) { 
                            // Place the image inside the dropzone
                            $('#dropped-files').append('<div class="image" style="background: #fff url('+image+') no-repeat;background-size: cover;background-position: center center;"> </div>'); 
                        }
                        else {

                            $('#extra-files .number').html('+'+($('#file-list li').length + 1));
                            // Show the extra files dialogue
                            $('#extra-files').show();

                            // Start adding the file name to the file list
                            $('#extra-files #file-list ul').append('<li>'+file.name+'</li>');

                        }
                    }; 

                })(files[index]);

            // For data URI purposes
            fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);

        });


    });

    function restartFiles() {

        // This is to set the loading bar back to its default state
        $('#loading-bar .loading-color').css({'width' : '0%'});
        $('#loading').css({'display' : 'none'});
        $('#loading-content').html(' ');
        // --------------------------------------------------------

        // We need to remove all the images and li elements as
        // appropriate. We'll also make the upload button disappear

        $('#upload-button').hide();
        $('#dropped-files > .image').remove();
        $('#extra-files #file-list li').remove();
        $('#extra-files').hide();
        $('#uploaded-holder').hide();
        $('#drop-files').show();

        // And finally, empty the array/set z to -40
        dataArray.length = 0;
        z = -40;

        return false;
    }

    $('#upload-button .upload').click(function() {

        $("#loading").show();
        var totalPercent = 100 / dataArray.length;
        var x = 0;
        var y = 0;

        $('#loading-content').html('Uploading '+dataArray[0].name);

        $.each(dataArray, function(index, file) {   
            bla = $('#gpID').val();


            $.post('/mods/photogallery/manager/upload.php?gpID=' + bla, dataArray[index], function(data) {

                var fileName = dataArray[index].name;
                ++x;

                // Change the bar to represent how much has loaded
                $('#loading-bar .loading-color').css({'width' : totalPercent*(x)+'%'});

                if(totalPercent*(x) == 100) {
                    // Show the upload is complete
                    $('#loading-content').html('Uploading Complete!');

                    // Reset everything when the loading is completed
                    setTimeout(restartFiles, 500);

                } else if(totalPercent*(x) < 100) {

                    // Show that the files are uploading
                    $('#loading-content').html('Uploading '+fileName);

                }

                // Show a message showing the file URL.
                var dataSplit = data.split(':');
                if(dataSplit[1] == 'uploaded successfully') {
                    alert('Upload Was Successfull');
                    var realData = '<li><a href="/mods/photogallery/photos/'+dataSplit[0]+'">'+fileName+'</a> '+dataSplit[1]+'</li>';



                    $('#drop-files').css({
    'background' :'url(/mods/photogallery/photos/' + dataSplit[0] + ') no-repeat',                      
    'background-size': 'cover',
   'background-position' : 'center center'
});

                    $('#uploaded-files').append('<li><a href="/mods/photogallery/photos/'+dataSplit[0]+'">'+fileName+'</a> '+dataSplit[1]+'</li>');

                    // Add things to local storage 
                    if(window.localStorage.length == 0) {
                        y = 0;
                    } else {
                        y = window.localStorage.length;
                    }

                    window.localStorage.setItem(y, realData);

                } else {
                    $('#uploaded-files').append('<li><a href="/mods/photogallery/photos/'+data+'. File Name: '+dataArray[index].name+'</li>');
                }

            });
        });

        return false;
    });

    // Just some styling for the drop file container.
    $('#drop-files').bind('dragenter', function() {
        $(this).css({'box-shadow' : 'inset 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)', 'border' : '4px dashed #bb2b2b'});
        return false;
    });

    $('#drop-files').bind('drop', function() {
        $(this).css({'box-shadow' : 'none', 'border' : '4px dashed rgba(0,0,0,0.2)'});
        return false;
    });

    // For the file list
    $('#extra-files .number').toggle(function() {
        $('#file-list').show();
    }, function() {
        $('#file-list').hide();
    });

    $('#dropped-files #upload-button .delete').click(restartFiles);

    // Append the localstorage the the uploaded files section
    if(window.localStorage.length > 0) {
        $('#uploaded-files').show();

        for (var t = 0; t < window.localStorage.length; t++) {
            var key = window.localStorage.key(t);
            var value = window.localStorage[key];
            // Append the list items
            if(value != undefined || value != '') {
                $('#uploaded-files').append(value);
            }
        }
    } else {
        $('#uploaded-files').hide();

    }
});
```

PHP

```
// We're putting all our files in a directory.
$uploaddir = '../photos/';

// The posted data, for reference
$file = $_POST['value'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$gpID = $_GET['gpID'];

// Get the mime
$getMime = explode('.', $name);
$mime = end($getMime);

// Separate out the data
$data = explode(',', $file);

// Encode it correctly
$encodedData = str_replace(' ','+',$data[1]);
$decodedData = base64_decode($encodedData);

// You can use the name given, or create a random name.
// We will create a random name!

$randomName = $gpID.'.'.$mime;




if(file_put_contents($uploaddir.$randomName, $decodedData)) {

$sql = "UPDATE zmods_galleriesphotos SET gpFile = '$randomName' WHERE gpID = '$gpID'";
$rows = $db->query($sql);




echo $randomName.":uploaded successfully";  


}
else {

echo "Something went wrong. Check that the file isn't corrupted";

}
```

Comment: whats php.ini upload_max_filesize say?

Comment: I think you need to increase your max upload filesize -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size

Comment: i dont think there is a php.ini file

Comment: how do i create that?

Comment: Yeah, check it with `echo ini_get("upload_max_filesize");` to be sure this is your problem. Then follow davidkonrad's link to fix it.

Comment: 32M was returned when echo upload max filesize

Comment: Possibly a problem with `localStorage`? Test with http://arty.name/localstorage.html

Comment: @kcdwayne if it is localStorage is there a way around this?

Comment: I haven't messed around with it much tbh. I would separate the JS and PHP and try them both independently to help narrow it down. See if you can upload the file without AJAX (using regular file input and submit). If it works you've taken out half of the guess work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the upload_max_filesize in your php.ini file (although it should be large enough by default)
2. Check the post_max_size as well
3. If you're uploading multiple files, then also check max_file_uploads
4. The fact that your sql is failing makes me wonder if this is a mysql problem and not a php problem. What is the SQL error that occurs?

Comment: the mysql only fails if image is not uploaded so it works for image upload less than the 800 kb.  32M for upload_max_filesize. No error just no update